# Forwarding Form Data to a @mail account and php forms

Tags: php, html, forms, web

Relatively new to web-design, I'm working on a simple website that I would like the website's end user to input form data and have their input be forwarded to a free @mail.com address. I have ran into two issues:

1. The form data is sent perfectly however, when the submit button is pressed the page renders the php form to the user, rather than being redirected to the first form html page. I have tried variations of the header function or the window.log(-1) in my PHP script however it has not been succesful.
2. The @mail.com account was recently blocked, my guess is it has to do the the script and the form data i've been directed to it.

I have enclosed the PHP script, if anyone can help with the issue I will be GREATLY appreciative!

Cheers!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $units = $_POST['units'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_contents .= "First Name: ".$fname."\n";
    $email_contents .= "Last Name: ".$lname."\n";
    $email_contents .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
    $email_contents .= "Number of Units: ".$units."\n";
    $email_contents .= "Location of Client: ".$location."\n";
    $email_contents .= "Message: ".$message."\n";

    $mailTo = 'thermopassca@mail.com';
    $headers = "From: ".$email;
    mail($mailTo,$units,$location,$email_contents,$headers);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your message has been sent to The Thermopass Team')</script>";
    // header("Location:http://www.thermopass.ca/greatness/contact.html");
}
?>

<!-- 


// $fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
// $lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
// $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
// $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

// //Check input fields 
// if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($fname) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message))
// {
//     echo "Please fill all the neccesary message fields ";
// }
// else 
// {
//     $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
//     $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

//     mail("thermopassca@mail.com",$subject,$txt,$headers);


//     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your message has been sent');
//         window.history.log(-1);
//         </script>";
// } -->
```

Comment: Use PHPMailer and never look back.

Comment: Hard to understand your question.  `The form data is sent perfectly` - does it mean the email is sent? Or the POST works? If the latter, how do you know?  Be specific, describe your observations.  `when the submit button is pressed the page renders the php form to the user` - does it mean you see PHP code displayed in the browser, like text? If so, your webserver is not set up to handle PHP.  How to fix that depends on what web server, and OS you are using, but search and you will find many thousands of guides.

Comment: Also, a suggestion - is the commented out code relevant? Are we supposed to read it as well?  Keep things simple, try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the less code there is the easier it is to read, understand, and help.